# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement in my app, that when I click on "Details", it goes to the "detalhesJogadores", but I'm not getting the error "returning undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)"

listaindex.js

```
   eslint-disable prettier/prettier
    import {Text, View,StyleSheet,Image,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import React, {Component} from 'react';


export default class JogadoresLista extends Component {
   detalhes = () => { this.props.navigation.navigate( 'Detalhes' )}
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewDentro}>
        <View style={styles.viewTop}>
          <Image source={this.props.imageUri} style={styles.imagem} />
            <View style={styles.viewBottom}>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{this.props.posicao}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botao} title="Detalhes"
                onPress={this.detalhes}>
                  <Text style={styles.textoB}>Detalhes</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}

}
```

detalhesJogadores.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-trailing-spaces */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {Text, View, Image,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';



export default class DetalhesJogadores extends Component {
  render(){

    return (
      <View style={styles.viewDentro}>
        <View style={styles.viewTop}>
            <View style={styles.viewBottom}>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>Deu Certo</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );  
}
}
```

index.js

```
This is the default page, where the user can click and go to the page

/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import JogadoresLista from '../jogadores/listaIndex';
import logoG from '../../images/icon.png';

export default function IndexPlayers() { 
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={styles.home}>
    <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}>
    <View style={styles.logoView}>
            <Image source={logoG} style={styles.imageLogo}/>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.texto}>Principais Jogadores</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textoL}>GodoySoccer</Text>
            </View>
      </View>
      <ScrollView horizontal={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <JogadoresLista
              imageUri={require('../../images/ronald-juv.jpg')}
              name="Cristiano Ronaldo"
              posicao="Extremo Esquerdo"/>
          </ScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCypo.png)
[page detalhesJogadores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW1iT.png)

I would like a help on how I should proceed in order to solve this problem because I don't know what I do anymore

Comment: As per my opinion you can try like this:-
onPress = { this.details }
and outside render define an arrow function named details like this:-
details = ( ) => { 
this.props.navigation.navigate( 'Detalhes' )
  }
this will work according to me.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I put it as you asked, but I had the same error, I edited the code part, to take a look if I did it right, do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Can  u send me routing page?

Comment: Remove title and add this i.e `import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';` to your screen.

Comment: It worked with the method that CevaComic talked about, but thank you very much for your attention bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your version without a class. This shoud work with the hook useNavigation.

This works fine for react-navigation v5.x

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

export default props => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const detalhes = () => navigation.navigate('Detalhes')
    // or , if you need to send params too 
    // const detalhes = id => navigation.navigate('Detalhes',{playerId: id})
    return (
      <View style={styles.viewDentro}>
        <View style={styles.viewTop}>
          <Image source={props.imageUri} style={styles.imagem} />
            <View style={styles.viewBottom}>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{props.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textoP}>{props.posicao}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.botao} title="Detalhes"
                onPress={detalhes}>
                  <Text style={styles.textoB}>Detalhes</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // styles here
})
```